# vs2013 sqlite3 error C4703

Tags: c++, sqlite, visual-studio-2013

I just moved my sqlite3 classes from vs2010 express to vs2013 express.
In visual studio 2010 all was fine and works as well.

But when ( with re-compilated lib ) I tried to run any kind of sqlite3's functions I get the same error in different place of code in sqlite.h :
*error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'p' used*

I documented myself and I read this warning ( that become error with SDL checks ) is fault of pointer not initialized to NULL or nullptr.

MSDN solutions are:

1 - /wd[error] or/and disable sdlchecks ( I dont want ! )

2 - fix the code by initializating ptrs with NULL or nullptr ( In this case I CANNOT ! )

Does anyone know the right solution to fix my problem ?

**Solution:**

Recompile sqlite.lib with #pragma warning ( disable : 4703 )

Comment: Are you using the latest sqlite source? I don't receive this error with 3.7.17.

Comment: @dauphic yes Im using lastest version ( 3.8.2 )

Comment: You can disable the warning (or SDL checks) for just sqlite3.c

Comment: @dauphic Nice Idea! I recompilated the lib this time with #pragma warning ( disable : 4703 ). It works, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

Recompile sqlite.lib with #pragma warning ( disable : 4703 )

Comment: In case of Visual Studio: Project Properties->C/C++->Advanced->Disable Specific Warnings